# Wicked_pdf cannot find template for pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to render a pdf with wicked pdf in my action.

```
def show
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.pdf do
              render pdf: "reciept"
            end
        end
    end
```

This works fine for html format, but gives me

```
Missing template /reciept with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

Installed gem 'wicked_pdf' and 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'.
Using rails 7.
Any help will be appriciated.

I Thought it was issue with gem so reinstalled the gem but nothing changed.

Comment: This looks like a typo "recipt" vs "reciept". Suggestion: the correct English would be "receipt".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that was not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you moved from rails 6 to rails 7, then you need to remove the `.html.erb` defined against any attribute (this includes layout).

###### rails 6

`render pdf: "receipt", template: 'pdf/receipt.html.erb', layout: "pdf.html.erb", formats: [:html]`

###### rails 7

`render pdf: "receipt", template: 'pdf/receipt', layout: "pdf", formats: [:html]`

Answer (score 1):

```
render pdf: "recipt", template: 'pdf/recipt', formats: [:html]
```

Must tell formats to html if using recipt.html.erb or else it will give missing template error in rails 7. For using .pfd.erb file, without formats work.